# No provider for Http

Tags: angular, typescript

I have issue with injecting HTTP into Angular 2 application. Few days ago it was working fine but now I have error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!

There is main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { LoginModule } from "./login/login.module";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(LoginModule);
```

Login module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule], // external modules for all components
    declarations: [LoginComponent], // component which belong to this module
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent] // component on load
})
export class LoginModule {
}
```

And finally LoginComponent in LoginModule

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from "../data/account.service";
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { LocalStorage } from '../storage/storage';

@Component({
    selector: 'tp-login',
    templateUrl: `app/login/login.html`,
    styleUrls: ['app/login/login.css'],
    providers: [AccountService, LocalStorage]

})
```

There is exception in LoginComponent about no HttpProvider.
Somone know how to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 11):

Good to incapsulate all your module dependencies into main class module inside `@ngModule` attribute

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

So you can be sure that when your module will be included as child dependency - all dependecies will be resolved before.

Comment: So then how do you define `appRoutes`? Can you show the code?

Comment: As example: `export const appRoutes: Routes = [{ path: 'users',  component: UserListComponent }];` Just as classic routes declaration

Comment: Import HttpClientModule instead since angular version v4.3+

Answer (score 4):

In the App Module.

Import `HttpModule` and `Http` from `@angular/http`:

```
import {HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend, Http} from "@angular/http";
```

Add the `HttpModule` to import property in `@NgModule` declarations:

```
imports: [
    HttpModule,
]
```

Provide `Http` in `Providers` property of `@NgModule`

```
providers: [
    {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions),rations
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]}
],
```

Answer (score 3):

First, remove the import { LoginModule } from "./login/login.module"; in your main.ts, it doesn't solve your problem.

Try importing **HttpModule** into your Login module file or in your root module:

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule], 
    declarations: [LoginComponent], // component which belong to this module
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent] // component on load
})
export class LoginModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `HttpModule` in your `component/` service file :

```
import { Http , HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
```

and then add it `HttpModule` in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Http ,HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
```

and in ngModules imports also

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule   ]
```